# How do I change clothes?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

I'm trying to figure out how to change my clothes - I read that it is in front of the mirror - but cant figure out what buttons to press? Do I use the stylus?

Comment: Are you talking about the very beginning of the game? If so, go in front of the mirror and press A

Comment: If you are asking about buying new clothes there are many different clothing stores in various towns throughout Kalos

Comment: yes at the very beginning of the game - my son could not figure it out.

Comment: Generally small question like this will get closed on this site. I'd be happy to help you with any further questions though.

Comment: @Kecoey A short and simple but still valid question should not be getting closed just because it's not very elaborate. You should post your original comment as an answer since, well, it is one.

Answer (score 1):

There are two seperate parts to changing clothes: The first time at your house, and out on your adventure.

At your house after you wake at the start of the game, stand in front of the mirror and press "A". This will change your clothes.

Later in the game, you can find clothing stores in various towns. You can change your outfit in the dressing room at the top right of the store, or in a Pokemon Center to the top left. In either case, simply interact with/enter the dressing room and you will get the change clothes menu.

In order to have the different outfits and items available, simply buy them at the stores by interacting with them. Note that only the items at the back, in the middle area of the wall, are for sale, and these change on a regular basis.

Answer (score 0):

You have to go to Pokemon centers or a boutique. To the right of the nurse in the Pokecenters is a place to do it.

Comment: The changing rooms are to the left. The Pokemart Is to the right.

Comment: @Kendra I guess that might be subjective, since it's to nurse Joy's right xD

Comment: Yes, but to the camera angle, and therefore the plater, it is to the left.

Comment: *"To the nurse's right"* implies you're using the nurse's perspective for bearings. *"To the right of the nurse"* implies you're using **your** perspective, when looking at the nurse.

Answer (score 0):

You can just check the dressing room (curtains) at any pokemon center or (I think) the mirror in your house. There's a menu of clothes to try. It's a simple vertical list of all clothes you own in a certain category, just select items to switch, no complicated controls. You can remove "accessory" items (worn on your hat) or socks/stockings by re-selecting the currently worn item, but most other items can't be removed (not even hats).

However you might need some different clothes to change into, I don't recall starting the game with any options. Towns you find with clothes will have "boutique" listed by them on the town map (george has a list). The first boutique is in the third town, right after the first forest, though it only has a selection of hats.